# XSS JS-AlertBox on Hugo

Tags: nginx, hugo

I am running some Hugo Websites with NGINX. Currently, with Version:

hugo v0.83.1-5AFE0A57 linux/amd64 BuildDate=2021-05-02T14:38:05Z VendorInfo=gohugoio

We found some Problems with for example this URL:

[https://gohugosite.example/asdf’onmouseover='alert(origin)’%2f…/](https://gohugosite.example/asdf%E2%80%99onmouseover=%27alert(origin)%E2%80%99%2f%E2%80%A6/)

When I hover over an Image or a heading “copy link” button, I get an JS-AlertBox

With a local test, it does not work. Only when I get it on Docker/NGINX Server or normal NGINX Server. Does anybody have the same Problem or a Solution?

Comment: I genuinely don't understand the question...
Also, the link isn't working (for me at least)...

Comment: When I open a site local (hugo server command) with `asdf’onmouseover='alert(origin)’%2f…/` in the ending than I will be redirected to the site without `asdf’onmouseover='alert(origin)’%2f…/` for example when I open this URL:

https://gohugosite.example/asdf’onmouseover='alert(origin)’%2f…/test/

I will be redirected to:

https://gohugosite.example/test/

My question now why this is not happining on NGINX Hosted Hugo Websites?

The link is just an example link. Its not a real link ;)

Comment: Pardon, my English isn't the best, so I'm trying to make sure I understand.
You wrote: Hugo server asdf...etc...
and are wondering why hugo didn't append asdf... as a query?
like: yoursite/about-us/?asdf....
My answer would be because that's not how the hugo server command works. 
If you have code that is adding and trying to parse a query?
That's what's not understandable just yet. Possibly even show the code in question, that would help.

Comment: @Regelio I think the user wants to prevent XSS attack/test the security of the NGINX Server. That is the reason for this experiment. This question has little to do with Hugo in my opinion.

Comment: @JoostS is right. I want to prevent XSS attacks. First I thought it was the docdock theme but now I am using theme-hugo-learn and the alert-boxes are also in other theme versions. I also think its an nginx error